# Why can't I call my id variable from my scss file?

Tags: html, css, sass

Here is my attempt at a website. This is the html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>firstwebsite</title>
    </head>
    <style>

    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="firstwebsite.css">

    <div>
        <img src="ManchesterLeaveLogo.png" alt="image cannot be displayed" width="30" height="30">
        <div >
            <h1 id= 'title'>Manchester</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</html>
```

Here is the SCSS:

```
<pre>
div{
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 50;
    background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}
#title{
    top: 500px;
    left: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: padding;
}
</pre>
```

I don't understand why, although my division with id= 'title' is being called by the scss file (and yes I did set the scss file to watching), it wont apply the positioning changes in my browser(edge) and I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

To make it more clear, I am trying to have "Manchester" appear next to the image. That is why I am trying to use #title in the scss file move the h1 heading with the id = "title".

Comment: Units are important with CSS, 50 what? Percent? Pixels? Em? Vh? [With `position:static`  everything in your  `#title` selector will be ignored with the exception of `visibility`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/#:~:text=static%20%3A%20every%20element%20has%20a,just%20like%20the%20static%20value.)

Comment: Also note that `show` is not valid for `visibility` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility. In general you should be using `padding` and/or `margin` for "in flow" positioning. Leave `top` ,`left` etc for elements taken out of the normal document flow.

Comment: With your edit, positioning is now being done. Note with `color:white` you wont see the text as `position:absolute` takes the title element out of the normal document flow and out of the containing `div` with a background color. What are you trying to achieve with `visibility:padding` ? Again that is not a valid value. What are you trying to achieve in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear exactly what you want, so I will take a guess that you want the title appearing 50px from the top and left yet still be within the bounding `div`. Margin on the title is what you want to use.

```css
div {
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 50;
  background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}

#title {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/30/30/" alt="image cannot be displayed" width="30" height="30">
  <div>
    <h1 id='title'>Manchester</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, don't forget to upvote and accept when you can

Comment: I can't upvote cause I don't have the rep to yet, but I did accept

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make css like this.

```
#title{
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    visibility: show;
}
```

or

```
#title{
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 10000;
    visibility: show;
}
```

or

```
#title{
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    visibility: show;
}
```